# How calculate Gini coefficient (unbiased) and Lorenz Curve with stratified sample?

Tags: stratification, finite-population, gini, survey-weights

I'm working with a stratified sample by minimum variance method with 3 levels that becomes at 1176 stratum. The sample comes from finite population of income taxes data.

I'm looking for how calculate the Gini index and Lorenz curve with this data.

Any help or guidance, like bibliography, would be appreciated.